# C/VHDL - Is there a way to generate .bit files

Tags: c, fpga

I have an FPGA which I would like to be able to configure from a C program, without having to use Xilinx ISE Design Tools.  Is there a way for me to generate a .bit file from a set of VHDL modules that have been previously created?

For Example:

Entity 1 has an input a and an output b

I want to be able to use C to connect the I/O to different entities and then generate the .bit file and upload it to the FPGA.

Comment: It's an interesting question but I'm not sure that Stack Overflow is an appropriate place for it. I've not voted for closing the question since I'm not certain here, but one of the standard reasons questions get closed is for asking for a library or tool to accomplish some task (which this question sounds like it is doing).

Comment: You have to run a synthesizer (XST or something else) and use the Xilinx backend P&R tools to get a bitstream. ISE is just a wrapper around a suite of command line tools that can be called directly from another program. This was done more commonly with the predecessors to ISE but will still work. Vivado has changed things to run in an integrated Tcl engine but I believe you can still control synthesis there without the GUI.

Comment: Ah, perfect, I could parse the VHDL with C and have a system call to run the synthesiser.  Found this: http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/41265.html

Comment: What you want is not practical. How will you make sure your .bit passes timings for example? I think you should have a look at partial reconfiguration, which allows you to reload some modules in your design, although every optional modules has to be synthesized beforehand.

Comment: You could also be interested in [HLS (High level synthesis)](http://www.xilinx.com/products/design-tools/vivado/integration/esl-design.html).